# Share text on Twitter without using Intent in app's background

Tags: android, twitter

I have list of product if I choose one product at that time that product share on Twitter with user name.

it is possible or not? if yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used this to solve above problem.

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/08/08/improved-twitter-oauth-android/

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/13/guide-to-integrating-twitter-android-application/

this is [code](https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidTwitterSample) which i used.

also i see some Twitter API to solve this question

hope it help to other.

all code i added here : http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2012/05/share-text-to-facebook-twitter-android.html

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html). Also, not sure if it requires using an intent, but you might check out the development section on the [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/) website. Looks like they have a REST API that you might be able to take advantage of.